# To add css property for particular tag of Div if class is foundJQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="b">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="a">
<p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
</div>
</div>
```

This is a piece of code in which I want to add css properties to `<h1>` of div with class "b" if `<p>` contains `class="ABC"`.
How to do it?

Comment: I cannot exactly understand what you are trying to do. Can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: If p has class ABC then I want to add some css property to h1 tag of div with class "b"

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

`if($('p').hasClass('ABC')){
    $('h1').addClass('b');
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if($(".b p.ABC").length)
```

To check if the element with the class `b` has a `p` tag as a child that has the class `ABC`.

You can then add css using `.css` to the appropriate element (here that element is `$(".b h1")`).

See working example below:

```js
if($(".b p.ABC").length) {
  $(".b h1").css({'color': 'red'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you had used length?

Comment: yeah, `$(".b p.ABC")` returns an array like structure (a jquery object) of elements which match the selector. If none do, then an empty array (an object with length 0) will be returned. An empty array has a length of `0`. `if($(".b p.ABC").length)` is the same as `if($(".b p.ABC").length > 0)`. So, here I am checking element exsists

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dot* in between the tag name and class to refer the element.

Try `$('div.b p.ABC')` as the selector:

`div.b` will select any div with class `b`

The following space indicate the next matched element (`p.ABC`) will be inside the previous element (`div.b`).

`p.ABC` will select any div with class `ABC`

```js
$('div.b p.ABC').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
  <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.b').each(function() {
   var b = $(this);
   var h1 = b.find('h1');
   var p = b.find('div.a p');
   if (p.is('[class="ABC"]')) {
      h1.css({color: 'red'});
   }
});
```

this check exact attribute `class="ABC"` if you want case insensitive you can use `p.is('.abc')` or `p.hasClass('abc')` and if you want if it have class ABC uppercase you can use `is('[class^="ABC "],[class$=" ABC"], [class="ABC"]')`